# How to return new json from a function within a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, coffeescript, promise

I have a mongoose query that finds a bunch of venues and then does a google query to find driving distances to those venues. that google function is inside a promise and in the .then I have to do `res.json venues.emitted.fulfill[0]` or else the json comes out wrapped with

```
  "emitter": {
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {
      "reject": [
        null,
        null
      ]
    },
    "_eventsCount": 2
  },
  "emitted": {
    "fulfill": [
      [... 
    ]
   ]

    ]
  },
  "ended": true
}
```

Is there any way to avoid returning all that from the promise so I can just do res.json or is this the best way to go about this?

Here's the relevant code(coffeescript):

```
Venue.find {}
  .lean()
  .then (dbResponse) ->
    venues = dbResponse
    if req.param('hotelId')
      hotelId = req.param('hotelId')
      distancePromise = ()->
        venues = findDistances(hotelId, venues, req)
      Promise.resolve distancePromise()
      .then ()->
        res.json venues.emitted.fulfill[0]
    else
      res.json venues
  .catch (err) ->
    res.status(400).send(err)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function that returns you a promise, you should get the value that the promise is returning you and then just send that value.

```
Venue.find {}
  .lean()
  .then (dbResponse) ->
    venues = dbResponse
    if req.param('hotelId')
      hotelId = req.param('hotelId')          
      findDistances(hotelId, venues, req)
      .then (result)->
        res.json result
      .catch (error) ->
        res.status(404).send(err)
    else
      res.json venues
  .catch (err) ->
    res.status(400).send(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `distancePromise` function does not return a Promise thus resolves instantly.
`findDistance` does return a Promise that resolves with the results as a fist argument.
That's what the properties you see "wrapping" the results.
Juste use

```
return findDistance()
.then(res.json)
```

Returning that Promise will allow catching errors with the last function.

```
Venue.find {}
  .lean()
  .then (dbResponse) ->
    venues = dbResponse
    if req.param('hotelId')
      hotelId = req.param('hotelId');
      return findDistances(hotelId, venues, req)
      .then (res.json)
    else
      return res.json venues
  .catch (err) ->
    res.status(400).send(err)
```